# What's the meaning of CWD in database design?

Tags: sql, database-design, schema, naming

What's the meaning of CWD?

Usually, It used in SQL Schema.

like cwd_user or cwd_directory.

I have seen it here [Jira database schema](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/attachments/jira-7-9-2-database-schema.pdf).

Comment: Is it meaning about Crowd?

Comment: @MitchWheat I think that no makes sense to cwd_directory. Is it not?

Comment: apparently it means crowd, but this is not a programming question

Comment: @MitchWheat I think also this is a portion of the programming.
Thank you for your opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an acronym of Atlassian's "Crowd" identity management software, see https://www.atlassian.com/software/crowd

Comment: Is it used as an acronym only in Atlassian?
I supposed It used generally somewhere.

Comment: Jira is by Atlassian, and Crowd is also by Atlassian.